# Should I ignore UnserInterfaceState and xcschememanagement files in git?

Tags: ios, git, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree with iOS project with Git question.

Two files are always in unstage file:

```
UnserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
xcschememanagement.plist
```

But, actually I haven't made a any change. (Maybe I just clicked one of files the in project in the Xcode window?)

Should I

- commit and push those two files?
- just ignore them by selecting "Ignore file"?
- "Remove file"?

I don't want to bother other team developers.

Usually, What is the best choice for those two files?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this file to `.gitignore` file so that git starts to ignore this file.